# Derivative of the nth order and evaluation in $x=0$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I want to solve the following exercise; be $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}e^x-\frac{1}{x^2}e^x+\frac{1}{x^2}$ with $x\neq 0$ we have that the function has derivatives in all orders for $x=0$

I want to determine $f^{(n)}(0)$

It seems that the above is equivalent to the expression $\frac{1}{a(n)}$ where $a(n)$ represents an expression in terms of n, now, how can I determine this derivative? any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Hint: $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} \left( xe^x - e^x +1 \right)$. Use Taylor Formula for $e^x$ at a point $x=0$ to immediatelly see that your function is infinitelly differentiable at $x=0$. With a little bit more careful work with coefficients of that Taylor expansion, you should be able to deduce $f^{(n)}(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

We know $f$ admits a Taylor expansion at $x=0$:
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^{k}(0)}{k!}x^k
\end{align*}
Denoting with $[x^n]$ the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series $f(x)$ we want to calculate
\begin{align*}
f^{(n)}(0)=n![x^n]f(x)
\end{align*}

> Recalling the series expansion
> \begin{align*}
> e^x=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^j}{j!}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
> we obtain for $n\geq 0$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f^{(n)}(0)}&=n![x^n]f(x)\\
> &=n![x^n]\left(\frac{1}{x}e^x-\frac{1}{x^2}e^x+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\\
> &=n!\left([x^{n+1}]e^x-[x^{n+2}]e^x\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)}\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{n+2}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we apply the rule $[x^p]x^qf(x)=[x^{p-q}]f(x)$ and note $[x^n]\frac{1}{x^2}=0$.
- In (3) we select the coefficient of $x^{n+1}$ and $x^{n+2}$ from the exponential function (1) and multiply with $n!$.